# Comparing user's input to multiple values

Tags: ruby

I am starting to learn programming and I have chosen to learn Ruby using Codecademy. However, I was trying to consolidate my learning but I just can't get this to work!

```
print "What is 2 + 2 ="
sum_var = gets.chomp
sum_var.downcase!
if sum_var == "four" || 4
   puts "Correct!"
  else sum_var != "four" || 4
   puts "Wrong! #{sum_var} is not the answer!"
end
```

It just returns 'Correct!' even if it is wrong.

Comment: What is the value that you think is wrong and the code returned correct?

Comment: @sawa Full code is a mess

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need write the code as below :

```
print "What is 2 + 2 ="
sum_var = gets.chomp
# don't need to apply the bang method like you did - sum_var.downcase!
if sum_var.downcase == "four" || sum_var == '4'
   puts "Correct!"
else # else don't need condition checking, so I removed.
   puts "Wrong! #{sum_var} is not the answer!"
end
```

`sum_var = gets.chomp` gives you a *string*, no where you are converting it to a number. So, evenif you are passing number from the console it became `"4"` or `"7"` etc.

Let me explain you also why always you got `"Correct!"` as a output

`sum_var == "four" || 4` - In this expression, whenever `sum_var` is not equal to `"four"`, your first expression was evaluated to `false`, but when control went to test the second expression, it found there `4`. You know in Ruby all objects are `true`, except `nil` and `false`. So `4` is considered as `true`. Thus in your code always `if` block was getting executed, and you were keep getting as the output `"Correct!"`.

Now in your code, some other mess you did, that I corrected in my above code.

Comment: All you need to say is that `==` has higher precedence than `||`, and since `||` has `4` (which is truthy) on one side, the whole condition is always evaluated truthy.

Comment: @sawa yes.. should I edit my post to include or keep it in the comment as you said.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code lies in the line

```
if sum_var == "four" || 4
```

The `==` will usually return `false`, so the second part will be evaluated because the precedence of `==` is higher than the precedence of `||`. Since all objects except `false` and `nil` are "truthy" in Ruby the expression will end up being `true` regardless of the users input. Correction as proposed by @ArupRakshit, just wanted to add some more reason to it.

Comment: @ArupRakshit: you are correct on this one, maybe I read your post to quickly (or to slowly before your last edit :-)

Comment: All you need to say is that `==` has higher precedence than `||`, and since `||` has `4` (which is truthy) on one side, the whole condition is always evaluated truthy.